# Upgrading javascript function. No experience

Tags: javascript, web

I'm creating a website with DreamWeaver, and I used a Spry widget, which is just a sidebar for navigation, and lets you open and close tabs by clicking on them. You can open multiple tabs, which is what I don't really like. I'd like it to close the open tab when a new tab is being opened (so you'll just have one open tab always).
I've never programmed with javascript, and I took a look at the code of the js file, and it did not look too hard to modify it. Here you have it: http://pastebin.com/eZAYE0kZ

I saw that the function that is executed when you open a tab is

```
Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onTabClick = function(e)
{
        if (this.isOpen())
                this.close();
        else
        {
                this.open();
        }


        this.focus();

        return this.stopPropagation(e);
};
```

, so I thought that modifying this one correctly, I could make it close the one that is open.
Also, I realyzed that there was a function at the bottom that its objective was to close all tabs (or Panels),

```
Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanelGroup.prototype.closeAllPanels = function()
{
        var cpanels = this.getPanels();
        var numCPanels = cpanels.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPanels; i++)
        {
                var w = this.getElementWidget(cpanels[i]);
                if (w && w.isOpen())
                        w.close();
        }
};
```

So I thought that by calling this function from the previous one (assuming I don't have like a millons tabs, so it won't make a big bucle), I could find the tab that is opened, and close it. So I modified the first one as I show,

```
Spry.Widget.CollapsiblePanel.prototype.onTabClick = function(e)
{
    if (this.isOpen())
        this.close();
    else
    {
        this.closeAllPanels();
        this.open();
    }


    this.focus();

    return this.stopPropagation(e);
};
```

But it's not even opening a tab now. I don't know where's the error as I've never coded in Javascript.

Comment: Open developer tools for you browser and see if you can see an error in the console. If there is an error try and fix, otherwise set a break point on onTabClick and see what is happing. In Firefox you will be wanting Firebug, in chrome Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+c), in IE I think they call it developer tool and F12 brings them up from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the closeAllPanels() function is a method of the CollapsiblePanelGroup class and not of CollapsiblePanel. You are trying to call this.closeAllPanels() when **this** is a CollapsiblePanel.

I'm not familiar with the widgets you are using, but I bet your Panel will give you some way to access the group it belongs to. Look for a property called **parent** or **group** or similar. Then you can call this.parent.closeAllPanels()

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'this.' from before closeAllPanels();

I haven't been involved with JavaScript much recently, but I believe that the keyword 'this' in relation to your function is referring to the control that fired the event, aka the tab you clicked.

This tab has no function called closeAllPanels() as that belongs to the page. This would cause a Null Reference Error and the rest of the script wouldn't run.